# Reading Oracle Explain plan

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

```
explain plan for 
    SELECT * FROM schema2.mv_a_data mv
      WHERE mv.routing_code_type_id    = 3
      AND mv.static_data_status_id    IN(5, 8)
      AND mv.acct_currency_ind_id NOT IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT te.acct_currency_ind_id 
          FROM schema1.tem_ele te 
          WHERE te.lis_tem_id IN      
                  (SELECT lis_tem_id 
                   FROM schema1.lis_tem 
                   WHERE lis_tem.template_type_id = 2
                   AND lis_tem.deleted_flag       = 'N'      )
      AND te.acct_currency_ind_id IS NOT NULL
    )
 ORDER BY mv.treasury_region_code, 
          mv.legal_entity_mnemonic, 
          mv.currency_code;

 select * 
 from TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('PLAN_TABLE', null,'ADVANCED'));
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Id  | Operation             | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |   892 |   318K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY         |           |   892 |   318K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI |           |   892 |   318K|    68   (0)| 00:00:01 | `
|   3 |    VIEW                | VW_NSO_1  |  1457 |  8742 |    11  (0) | 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN          |           |  1457 | 33511 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | lis_tem   |   100 |  1100 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | tem_ele   |  3271 | 39252 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  7 |    MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL| mv_a_data |  2348 |   825K|    57   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

I am trying to read the given explain plan. After looking at the explain plan and according 
    to my understanding, first of all, FTS of LIS_TEM table and TEM_ELE are done and then they are joined using HASH JOIN.

**Question 1** - can I change this HASH JOIN to NESTED LOOP?

I am asking just for learning purpose. I know HASH JOIN is good here.
        After HASH JOIN, I guess it is going to ID3 ie VIEW VW_NSO_1 and ID7 MAT_VIEW.

**Question 2** - what is this VIEW VW_NSO_1, which clause of the SQL query was responsible to brought it here?
**Question 3** - How I will read the rest of the plan?
**Question 4** - Why HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI came in picture?

Please assist me to understand the above explain plan in detail. Thanks and let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 4):

> "can I change this HASH JOIN to NESTED LOOP?"

You can try the `use_nl` hint. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51098)

> "what is this VIEW VW_NSO_1, which clause of the SQL query was responsible to brought it here?"

`VW_NSO_1` indicates the unnesting of the `IN` sub-query into a view. That is because your sub-query uses DISTINCT, so guarantees a unique set. This operation isn't documented in the 11g docs but [you can find it in the older Tuning Guides.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/opt_ops.htm)

> "How I will read the rest of the plan?"

Ummm, with due attention to detail? Basically all the tables involved are small enough and lack helpful indexes, so the optimizer has plumped for Full table Scans.

> "Why HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI came in picture?"

Think of the `NOT IN` sub-query as a sort of an outer join. You want records in the MView which don't match rows in the sub-query - an anti-join. In your query that would be a LEFT OUTER JOIN. However, the optimizer has decided it would be more efficient to gather the result set of the sub-query first than evaluate the anti-join on the MView, which is a right outer join. Dion Cho wrote a very good piece on this. [Find out more](https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/right-join-the-secret-of-swapping-join-input/).

Answer (score 1):

The view VW_NSO_1 is your inline view in your query:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT te.acct_currency_ind_id 
          FROM schema1.tem_ele te 
          WHERE te.lis_tem_id IN      
                  (SELECT lis_tem_id 
                   FROM schema1.lis_tem 
                   WHERE lis_tem.template_type_id = 2
                   AND lis_tem.deleted_flag       = 'N'      )
      AND te.acct_currency_ind_id IS NOT NULL
    )
```

The optimiser has converted your "in" clause to a hash join.
It has also converted your "not in" clause to hash join right anti.

All your tables are quite small so full scan is nothing to be concerned about -
the optimiser has probably chosen the best tactic for your data.

Comment: Thanks all. Very useful info.
As I said I am also trying to read the explain plan like this, 
first ID5 FTS of LIS_TEM is done then ID6 FTS of TEM_ELE is done. 
After this these 2 tables are joined with HASH JOIN.
After this "ID3 - VIEW - VW_NSO_1" and "ID7 - MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL - MV_A_DATA" are in the same line. So optimizer is scanning all the WHERE clauses of MAT_VIEW (prefix mv. ) as well as VW_NSO_1 clause.

Then how HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI is linked with ID3 and ID7?

Comment: Or HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI is only linked with ID3 VIEW? If this is correct, then  SORT ORDER BY operation is being done on the result of ID2 and ID7?
Or I cannot read the explain plan in this way?
Can you guys please tell me how you would read this explain plan?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query hints to 'force' a query to use a specific join although i wouldn't recommend it. If its using a hash then it is probably the best thing for it. Make sure your statistics are upto date if you think it would be better using a different join

Oracle docs are helpful to look at what each operation is doing:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: can you or someone please answer question2, 3 and 4?